# How to run multiple command or javascripts into frida?

Tags: adb, frida

So i was running this code :

```
frida -U -f owasp.mstg.uncrackable2 -l who-does-it-call.js -l aesinfo.js -l fridantiroot.js
```

and the output is :

```
Spawned `owasp.mstg.uncrackable2`. Resuming main thread!
Error: could not parse 'C:\adb\platform-tools\Tugas Frida\fridantiroot.js' line 1: expecting ';'
    at <anonymous> (/frida/repl-4.js:1)
```

I tried another way that i only use one scripts like this:

```
frida -U -f owasp.mstg.uncrackable2 -l fridantiroot.js
```

But the output is the same...

Im using the scripts from fridacodeshare.

Is there something that i missed or wrong command?

I tried many ways below.

Comment: I assume you made a mistake when saving the fridantiroot.js script file from fridacodeshare. Make sure you have correctly downloaded the script file.

Comment: i didnt downloaded the script but copy paste from fridacodeshare and make new file with js extension.. is it wrong?

Comment: May be your editor added an UTF-8 BOM or something like this. The frida code share doesn't seem to be designed to download the scripts manually. Frida internally downloads the script inside a JSON structure so there is no other way than to copy and paste the script text, but make sure to use an editor that doesn't adds anything like a BOM.

Comment: im using notepad.. or should i use notepad++? is there other way to download fridacodeshare, the javascript?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Frida seems to load the code embedded in a JSON structure so using this interface would require to JSON unescape the whole script.